# Google App Engine - Python appication: find relationship among nodes

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I have following model:

```
class Relations(db.Model):
    name = db.StringProperty()
    events = db.StringListProperty(required = True)
```

and following Relations data:

```
name = direct  events = [node_A,event_B],
name = inverse events = [node_A,node_G],
name = direct  events = [node_A,node_H],
name = inverse events = [node_A,node_X],
name = direct  events = [node_A,node_Y]
```

and based on user input (e.g node_A up) I need to find the relationship among nodes and output the nodes as follows:

output: node_B - up, node_G - down, node_H - up, node_X - down, node_Y - up

In other words I need queries to find out relationship among nodes for example, if relationship of node_A to node_B is direct and node_A to node_X is inverse output will be node_B - up and node_X - down as in the output example above.

If user input will be node_G down then output required is node_A down since there are no other nodes related to node_G except node_A.

Please suggest the queries. Thanks in advance
Prakash

Comment: What does the "up" in the user input signify? In your example, you're outputting all of the nodes connected to A whether the relationship is up or down.

Comment: Why are you using a `StringListProperty` instead of a `ListProperty(db.Key)`?

Comment: I am new to python and google app engine. My application is working using StringListProperty. Can you suggest how can I benefit using ListProperty(db.Key) instead of StringListProperty in terms of my app logic?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, something like this could work:

```
query = Relations.all()
query.filter('events =', node)

direct_list = []
inverse_list = []

for relation in query:
  relation.events.remove(node)
  if relation.name == 'direct':
    direct_list.extend(relation.events)
  else:
    inverse_list.extend(relation.events)

if action == 'up':
  #direct_list is all 'up'
  #inverse_list is all 'down'
else:
  #opposite of above
```

Comment: Hi hyperslug, Thanks for excellent suggestion. One problem I found is that for input 'event_A down' I am finding output as event_B up, event_H up, event_Y up, event_G down, event_X down instead of just event_G down, event_X down. Can you please suggest how I can modify the code you have suggested.

Comment: Above, you defined A as the inverse of G and X.  When A is down, should G and X be up?

Comment: Yes, A is inverse of G and X so the output should be G and X down but output is H, Y and G up also, total count of 5 instead of 2. Seems I have implemented opposite wrongly. Here is my code: if 'up' == direction.lower():
            for itemU in direct_list:
                print(itemU + ' up')
            for itemD in inverse_list:
                print(itemD) + ' down')
           else:
            for itemU in direct_list:
                print(itemU) +   'up')
            for itemD in inverse_list:
                print(itemD) + '  down')

Comment: I just noticed I have to remove 'for itemU in direct_list: print(itemU) +   'up')' from the else part. Can you please confirm?

Comment: Not sure what you're trying to output.  This? `if 'up' == direction.lower(): for itemU in direct_list: print(itemU + ' up') for itemD in inverse_list: print(itemD) + ' down') else: for itemU in inverse_list: print(itemU) + ' up')`

Comment: That is your if else part implemention. Not possible to post whole code in comment. Here is stripped-down version: 
inputEvent = self.request.get('Input') words = inputEvent.split() event = words[0] direction = words[1] 
query.filter('events =', event) direct_list = [] inverse_list = [] for relation in query:relation.events.remove(event)if relation.name == 'Direct':direct_list.extend(relation.events)else:inverse_list.extend(relation.events). I think IF part is correct but the line in ELSE part 'for itemU in inverse_list: print(itemU) + ' up')' is redundant

Comment: and ELSE part should be only 'for itemD in inverse_list: print(itemD) + ' down')'. I hope I am clear.

Comment: Hi @hyperslug I am finding other problem in the logic but I think it's all because of wrong IF ELSE part implementation. I am correcting that part and will get back to you if I could not. Thanks again.